# Data binding combobox with list from WCF Service

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, mvvm, combobox

I am developing an app(MVVM pattern) for windows store using WCF service to receive data from database.
I want to data bind a list of categories into combobox, but it's not working for me, I searched the web and still didn't find a solution.

Class Category:

```
   public Category(Category c)
    {
        this.Id=c.Id;
        this.Name = c.Name;

    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
```

Xaml:

```
 <ComboBox x:Name="ChooseCategory"
   ItemsSource="{Binding ListCategories}"
                  DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                  SelectedValuePath="Id"
                  SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

ViewModel:

```
public ObservableCollection<Category> ListCategories { get; private set; }
```

in the OnNavigatedTo function:

```
   var listCategory = await proxy.GetAllCategoriesAsync();
            List<Category> list = new List<Category>();
            foreach (var item in listCategory)
            {

                list.Add(new Category(item));
            }
            ListCategories = new ObservableCollection<Category>(list);
```

Anyone???

Comment: Did you debug as to what was actually failing?  Are you actually getting values in the OnNavigatedTo function?  Are there errors in the Output section?  Does your ViewModel implement INotifyPropertyChanged?  More info, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in order to let UI know that you have changed the  `ListCategories` collection.

In your ViewModel, implement interface `INotifyPropertyChanged`

```
public class YourViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Category> _categories;
    public ObservableCollection<Category> ListCategories
    {
        get { return _categories; }
        set
        {
            if (_categories != value)
            {
                _categories = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ListCategories");
            }
        }
    }
```